# Prometheus alert on message sent to deal letter queue

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I made a gauge with amount of messages sit in DLQ. why gauge? because amount of messages can not only increase but also decrease when issue with event fixed.

But to find that something is in the DLQ developer should be notified (no one sitting and checking queue all the time, right?).

I'm a bit new to prometheus and alerting, is there a way to configure alerting in a way to send alert each time qauege value going up with amount on how much it increased???  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [delta function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) to detect changes. It returns the delta between the value at the end and start of the provided time range. For example:

```
delta(dlq_size_total[5m]) > 0
```

But maybe it would be simpler to just track additions to the DLQ as a separate counter.